# iterating a value each time a function is called

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, static

How can I achieve something like this? I have this function submit that's in another function that's called very often.

I would like to update the `idx` variable so that it's incremented by 1 to serve as an offset into a dynamic array.

```
int idx = 0;
float* abc;  //initialized to 18 floats
float* a, *b, *c; //each initialized to 3 floating values

//set some variable that's updated once submit is called to know where to offset the memory
void submit() {
    int local_idx = idx;
    abc[local_idx++] = a[0]; //first call to submit(), local idx starts at 0
    abc[local_idx++] = b[0];
    abc[local_idx++] = c[0];

    abc[local_idx++] = a[1];
    abc[local_idx++] = b[1];
    abc[local_idx++] = c[1];

    abc[local_idx++] = a[2];
    abc[local_idx++] = b[2];
    abc[local_idx++] = c[2];  //first call to submit(), local idx ends at 8
}


void update() {
    //do work   //fill 3 new values into *a, *b, *c
    submit();   //here idx = 0
    //do work   //fill 3 new values into *a, *b, *c
    submit();   //here idx = 1
    //do work   //fill 3 new values into *a, *b, *c
    submit();   // here idx = 2 etc....
}
```

that way each time I call `submit()` the `idx` value will increment by 1.

so on the first call to submit `idx = 0, local_idx = 0` and the array gets values 0-5 filled in.

Then on the next call global `idx = 5`, `local_idx = 5` then elements 6,12 are filled in. I've tried copying the value of `local_idx` back to the global `idx` value but that just makes the number run to infinity.

How can I write a control statement so to control this flow of data? I'd like to go

```
submit() //0  fills in elements 0-5
submit() //1  fills in elements 6-12
submit() //2  fills in elements 13-19
//.....
```

**edit**
here's the code that I am working with.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    //--------------- start update vertex data ---------------------

    sp = sprites[i];
    vmathT3MakeIdentity(&rotation);
    vmathT3MakeIdentity(&scale);
    vmathT3MakeIdentity(&translation);
    vmathT3MakeIdentity(&ttmp);

    vmathT3MakeScale(&scal, &sp->scale);
    vmathT3MakeRotationZYX(&rotation, &sp->angle);
    vmathT3MakeTranslation(&translation, &sp->pos);
    vmathT3Mul(&tmp, &translation, &scale);
    vmathT3Mul(&tmp, &tmp, &rotation);

    vmathM4MakeFromT3(&sprites[i]->model_mat, &tmp);

    cg_quad_getquadverts(&sp->in_vec30, &sp->invec31, &sp->invec32, &sp->invec33, sp->quad);

    vmathM4MulV4(&sp->outvec0, &sp->m_mat, &sp->invec30);
    vmathM4MulV4(&sp->outvec1, &sp->m_mat, &sp->invec31);
    vmathM4MulV4(&sp->outvec2, &sp->m_mat, &sp->invec32);
    vmathM4MulV4(&sp->outvec3, &sp->m_mat, &sp->invec33);
}
```

at this point I have all the data that I need in the outvec[x] variables and some variables in the sprite structure.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    sp = sprites[i];
    idx = 0;
    // v0
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->outvec30.x;
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->outvec31.y;
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->outvec32.z;

    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[0];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[1];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[2];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[3];

    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[0];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[1];

    // v1
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->outvec31.x;
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->outvec31.y;
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->outvec31.z;

    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[4];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[5];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[6];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[7];

    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[2];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[3];

    // v2
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->outvec32.x;
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->outvec32.y;
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->outvec32.z;

    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[8];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[9];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[10];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[11];

    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[4];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[5];

    // v3
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->outvec33.x;
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->outvec33.y;
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->outvec33.z;

    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[12];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[13];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[14];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->colors[15];

    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[6];
    v_buff[idx++] = sp->quad->tex_coords[7];
}
```

That is the code that I wrote and I am working with currently and it works but I need to abstract it out a bit. Going in manually changing those variables leads to errors.

What I would like to do is instead of  having this giant chunk of code right in the middle of my project, just put it away in a function. A function such as

```
submit(sprite* s);
```

which will take that sprite, do the matrix transformations on the data then append the outvec, color, uv onto the v_buff at the correct spot.

but so far my attempts at putting this inside a function have failed. It's not terribly complex code but I am just not seeing how I could abstract this function away.

Is there anyone who can advise me how to put this above code in a function so that I can call it multiple times per loop without it totally thrashing the data that's already stored in v_buff?

Comment: `local_idx` ends at `9`, not `8`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filling an array in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855447/filling-an-array-in-a-loop)

Comment: If you initialize `abc` so it can hold 18 values, calling `submit()` 3 times will give you problems as it writes to elements indexed by 18..26 which are way out of bounds.

Comment: Not sure why you use a disting `submit` function anyway. Why not just use a 3-entry part of the array for the "do work ..." parts. Just increment a pointer by 3 afterwards instead of calling `submit`.

Comment: the question isn't a duplicate, if take a look at the question being referenced you'll see that I asked that question as well and accepted an answer. I created a new question to expand on that instead of trying to add code to a tiny comment box when I though that space was inadequate to get a full though out.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your `submit()` function a number for value:

```
submit(0)
submit(5)
submit(6)
```

and in your function `submit()`, assign the value to `local_idx`; you can use a `for` loop, or some loop, but this is optional.

In another way, you can use the static value for `idx` too; you need to use a static variable in the function, and the value will be saved between calls.

Comment: note: this is better than the static variable solutions, because it would work in a multi-threaded scenario, and it allows for more than one other function to use this mechanism simultaneously, and it's easier to reset the variable if required.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, what you need is to define `local_idx` as a `static` variable.

Or, for better, get rid of the `local_idx` altogether, make the `idx` itself as `static` and use the same as the index.

In that case,

- It will *hold* it's value between successive calls to the function. (*retains
  its last-stored value throughout its lifetime, which is the entire execution, see below*)
- will be initialized only once.

To elaborate on `static` storage class specifier, quoting `C11` standard, chapter §6.2.4,

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier
>   `_Thread_local`, and either with external or internal linkage **or with the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the
>   program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.**

That said, you need to ensure that the index value used for `abc` is valid, to avoid the [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by running out of bounds.

Comment: I'm not convinced that making it into a static variable within the function is useful — or, at least, it means there is no way to reset the value back to zero unless you code it.  At least when it is a file static (or fully global, as now), you can reset the index back to 0 when appropriate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was adding the edit from the point of reducing the variable number, but your point seems more valid sir.  anyways, I've updated the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable static. For example

```
void submit() {
    static int idx;
    int local_idx = idx++;

    if ( idx > SomePredefinedValue ) idx = 0;

    abc[local_idx++] = a[0]; //first call to submit(), local idx starts at 0
    abc[local_idx++] = b[0];
    abc[local_idx++] = c[0];

    abc[local_idx++] = a[1];
    abc[local_idx++] = b[1];
    abc[local_idx++] = c[1];

    abc[local_idx++] = a[2];
    abc[local_idx++] = b[2];
    abc[local_idx++] = c[2];  //first call to submit(), local idx ends at 8
}
```